Can the Lorentz force cause currents that accelerate electrons and cause auroras?
I'm asking this question based on a fragment of this (https://pubs.aip.org/physicstoday/article-abstract/61/7/68/1017143/How-do-auroras-form-A-key-element-is-a-current?redirectedFrom=PDF)

If the Lorentz force imposed on the ionosphere by the horizontal currents requires field-aligned currents much larger than the thermal current, then a parallel electric field will arise that accelerates the electrons into the loss cone. Hence, one observes the discrete aurora as subsequent collisions occur.

And also from here (https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19820040213):

The dynamo power generates the convective motion of magnetospheric plasma, and subsequent magnetic-field aligned currents communicate the dynamo power to the polar ionosphere. The currents close as Pederson currents, and the associated Lorentz force accelerates the ionosphere in the direction of the convective motion. An electric potential structure develops at a few thousand km height, forcing current-carrying electrons to flow down the field lines to the ionosphere, where interactions with atmospheric constituents create auroral displays.

Does it mean that the Lorentz force from Earth's magnetic field can cause currents that accelerate electrons and cause auroras upon collision with the atmosphere?
